# Blender Fracture Modifier locking to another mesh

Tags: modifiers, constraints

I am using the Fracture Modifier build of blender and have recreated a door in blender. I have the door's handle as a separate object, and I need the door handle to attach to the door as it is breaking. Adding an object constraint unfortunately doesn't work because the Fracture Modifier build adds a modifier, thus the positions of the shards in the door stay at the same location even after the door is shattered. I need a way to lock the door's handle to the door so that after the door is smashed, the handle will continue to fall with the wood shards it's attached to. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a fracture modifier to the handle too, setting shard count to 1 if you dont want it shattered. But it is important it is an FM object in order to use "Automation" -> "Combine" -> "Connect" in the fracture helper addon which is shipped with the fracture modifier build. (Needs FM 2.79a or newer.)

This will connect FM objects with external constraints where the objects "touch" basically. You can control the properties of the external constraints on the newly generated helper object (which has also an FM, but only maintains the constraints).

Alternatively you can setup the connection manually. In order to do so you can put the desired FM objects into a group, then create another helper object manually. Put an FM onto it, disable all sources. Specify the Group in "Sub object group" and check "Constraints only"... also enable "Use constraints in the helper object. But note, its easier to let the addon do the boring automation work.

Here I quickly built an example file with a simple door :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the door handle doesn't need to be a separate mesh you can try joining it to the shard that it is initially connected to by selected both meshes and pressing Ctrl + J. If the handle does need to be its own mesh you can try parenting it to a shard by selected both and pressing Ctrl + P.